Cannot get SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration to run correctly
I'm trying to set the IP address of network adaptors in my swift program and am getting stuck with actually getting SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration to work, my swift knowledge is limited and I'm struggling to find any information or examples online as to how I can make it work, any advice would be really appreciated.
let ipv4Config = [
   kSCPropNetIPv4Addresses: "192.168.45.40",
   kSCPropNetIPv4SubnetMasks: "255.255.255.0"
] as CFDictionary
        
if SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration(serviceIDString as AnyObject as! SCNetworkInterface, ipv4Config) {
   print("success") } 
      else {
   print("failed")
      }

The above fails.

How does it fail? Do you get an error message?

In its current configuration it just executes the fail in the if statement. However as  if SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration(serviceIDString as! SCNetworkInterface, ipv4Config) { it crashes with Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: failed cast

What is serviceIDString? You need an SCNetworkInterfaceRef, probably obtained from SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll. You can't just assume that en0 or whatever is the name of the interface that you want to configure.
